# Searching for SD-cards

Tags: c#, removable-storage

I need to implement searching for SD-cards in my program.

Currently I'm using search for all removable devices like:

```
searcher = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("\\localhost\root\cimv2", "SELECT DeviceId FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=2 AND Size>0");
```

But it find USB flash drives also. Is there a proper way to find SD-cards only?
What I need is in general only drive letter for available SD-cards (like "F:" or so).

Answer (score 5):

The SD cards use to have an unique ID. USB memories not. So you can use that to distinguish from USB and the SD card. I have used it in windows ce and was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible - Windows doesn't distinguish an SD card in a card reader from a USB stick.  In fact I'd bet that in most cases these days they're actually the same thing (i.e. memory stick = SD-card-on-a-USB-plug).

Comment: there was an answer I've posted comment to, that I had a program (forgot it's name, but will search) for file recovering (as far as i remember) that actually was showing only SD-cards and not showing my USB-sticks. So somehow it's possible