# Detecting SD Card drives

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, mfc, sd-card

My program needs to find out SD Cards among all local drives. One can easily identify removable drives (using `GetLogicalDrivesStrings()` and `GetDriveType()` ) but knowing which ones are truly SD cards seems harder.

There are quite a few questions (including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31559121/12379), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2453127/12379), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27131027/12379) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3462264/12379)) but no complete answer (many focus on USB). Some say it is impossible to distinguish SD Cards from USB, however Windows Explorer displays different drive icons for SD cards (at least in Windows 7) hence it does distinguish which is which.

Extra bonus for code NOT based on WMI since my program is still using native Win32/MFC! Can some `DeviceIoControl()` properties help? Now, if someone has a C#/.NET solution, I'd still happily read it!

Comment: Easy cheat; since the shell knows the type, ask the shell. Use `SHGetFileInfo` to get the icon index for the drive.

Comment: Haha! You've earned the Gold Badge _Dirty-yet-funny-and-even-maybe-effective solution_.  Let me just check the icon index on all versions of Windows! I might end up using your solution, which would show how desperate I am :-D

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with [DevicePowerEnumDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa372681(v=vs.85).aspx)

A USB Flash Drive should have `PDCAP_D2_SUPPORTED` under "Power data" in Device Manager, but not a memory card.

See discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52ef77fd-c59e-41b9-959d-3f1fbababfb0/getting-drive-info-for-sd-card?forum=csharplanguage)